# How to use VideoJS to show 360 video on Angular App

Tags: video, video.js, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I want to create a page with a 360 video player, so when I click play I need to be able to move the video and rotate 360 to see all the content.

So I created the video source in HTML and installed videojs, videojs-vr and vidoejs-panorama-player from npm.

```
<video id="videojs-panorama-player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" crossorigin="anonymous" controls width="1000">
  <source src="Ayutthaya.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

I can now see the video on the page and if I click play the video is playing, but not doing 360.
[image]
I have an angular application so I suppose I should do something via the typescript code, but what?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like VideoJS and the videojs-vr plugin does not know that your video is a 360 video.

This is a common problem with 360 videos as there are different ways to signal that a video is 360 in the video Metadata and not all elements in the video pipeline will be aware and preserve these.

VideoJS have some information on this in one of their blog posts - https://blog.videojs.com/videojs-vr-now-under-the-video-js-org/

The relevant section for you is probably this extract:

> The browser does not expose video metadata in an API so we would have to parse it ourselves, which isn’t really an option. So in videojs-vr we have a projection option that can be passed in during plugin initialization.
>
> The first and default setting for projection is 'AUTO'. Setting projection to 'AUTO' tells videojs-vr to look at player.mediainfo.projection. player.mediainfo.projection will have to be set by some external plugin/script which is told by a server that the current video is 360/VR. The player.mediainfo.projection of a video can be any of the following:
>
> - '360', 'Sphere', or 'equirectangular': The video is a sphere
> - 'Cube' or '360_CUBE': The video is a cube
> - 'NONE': This video is not a 360 video, the videojs-vr plugin should do nothing. this would not have to be set as it will be assumed if no projection exists.
> - '360_LR': Used for side-by-side 360 videos
>     '360_TB': Used for top-to-bottom 360 videos
>
> Otherwise, the projection can manually be set on plugin initialization to any of the above values. The plugin can then be disposed and re-initialized for each video with a different setting.

For your case it may be worth experimenting with setting the projection manually to find a setting that works for your video.

Comment: Take a look at the section 'Passing a projection on a source by source basis' in the README instructions: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-vr#passing-a-projection-on-a-source-by-source-basis